# Does the steganography process need a specific key?

Tags: key, steganography

I have a simply question. If the criptography process needs a specific key in order to encrypt the message... Does the steganography process(for example during a LSB inserction) needs also a key in order to makes a possible comunication invisible to third parties? And if the answer at this question is 'yes', how it is used?

Answer (score 0):

Key can be used as a seed for RNG, which gives us random pixel offsets. This makes steganalysis much more difficult.

So by definition a key is usually not needed (not with most algorithms at least), but highly preferred.